# Altering database getting error

Tags: sql-server

My database is showing read only. So i tray to change data base read only property to `False(databae->rightclik->property-option->database Readonly=>false`) after clicking ok button getting some error:

```
Alter failed for Database 'Vallett'. 
Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\Vallett.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\Vallett_1.ldf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
Database 'Vallett' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for details.
ALTER DATABASE statement failed. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)
```

Comment: Does the SQL Server service account have permission to write to those files?

Comment: How I can Check that??

Comment: You can check this in Windows Explorer properties for the files (security tab). Also check that the files themselves don't have the "readonly" attribute checked.

Comment: yes sir.  i have permission to write this files

Comment: My self resolved problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you resolved the question, you should either post your answer (as an answer, not in the question) or delete the question.

Comment: @AndersUP Post the answer if you have it, do not delete the question. If there is a solution, you should share it with everyone else. It may help others in the future

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Please read my comment. I don't have the answer. The OP writes that he has resolved the question himself, and I primarily suggested that he provide the answer or, given that the question might be better suited at dba.stackexchange.com, delete it all together.

Comment: @AndersUP I know you don't have the answer, I was just telling you that it is never a good idea to delete the question if you have the answer to it.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I disagree. Under some circumstances it will be the right thing to do - and this is one of these questions where, if the OP knows he's never going to come back to this question, never going to add details as to why this occured or even provide an answer as to what fixed it, especially since this question as it stands seems to be better suited at dba.stackexchange.com